# persistent selenium cookies in python

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, cookies

I have a test case in which the user shuts down the browser and re-opens it, to test if some login cookies are loaded correctly.

[One of the suggested ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058462/how-to-save-and-load-cookies-using-python-selenium-webdriver) was

```
browser.get("domain1.com")
cookies_domain1 = browser.get_cookies()
browser.get("domain2.com")
cookies_domain2 = browser.get_cookies()
//close browser

//re-open browser
browser.get("domain1.com")
for cookie in cookies_domain1:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
browser.get("domain2.com")
for cookie in cookies_domain2:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

But this doesn't look good. I need the cookies loaded before opening the page. Selenium seems to allow only adding the cookies from a page to that page only!

Another way i've tried to do this was to save the `browser.profile.path` directory, back it up, and on re-connect, pass it on a `FirefoxProfile`, which gets passed to a `webdriver.Firefox(FirefoxProfile(path_to_directory_backup))`. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to save the cookies.

Comment: There is no way at all in Selenium Webdriver to add the cookies before loading the webpage.

Comment: Can you explain why you would need to load the cookies prior to loading the page?  Couldn't you load the page, load the cookies, then refresh?  What behavior are you trying to replicate?

Comment: The behaviour is the user loading a page for which it already has cookies and seeing the correct content from the first shot. There are multiple domains involved in the test case, and i can't simply run around each of them to re-create the cookies. I'm testing a adserver display thing, and everything is filled from a different site.

Comment: I have a similar problem - users log in and their cookies should remain for a few years. I want to test it with Selenium. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63901136/using-permanent-profiles-and-cookies-in-selenium

Comment: There's an answer in the linked question that explains how to save the Firefox profile to a directory.