# How to set subdomain cookies in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, cookies

I'm willing to save an authorization cookie to not enter credentials again every time when I'm doing a online shop automation.

I have saved cookies after login as described there [How to save and load cookies using python selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058462/how-to-save-and-load-cookies-using-python-selenium-webdriver). 
After test run I am downloading shop page to have same cookies domain and webdriver domain. But there is a lot of subdomain cookies looking like this one and I'm getting an exception when I am trying to set it to webdriver

```
'.online-shop.com'
```

There are no subdomains in the HTTP conversation I have recoreded during login process. Selenium doesn't allow set cookie of another domain and I can't set subdomain cookie.

E.g. I cant do the following (I am getting exception):

```
for cookie in driver.get_cookies():
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

Is there a way to set subdomain cookies?