# Python, selenium opening my url on different windows of browser everytime

Tags: python, selenium

I am a newbie of python and I am trying to write a script that goes to Instagram, checks if logged in, if not logged in logs in with a given username and password.

The program works fine but every time I run it, it opens a different chrome window and does the work even there is already an opened chrome. Also, it does not save the logins, I run the program, it logs in Instagram, I do not logout and when I run again, with a new window of chrome, it is not logged in so I do not know much about browsers but it is like does not save or check cookies or something like that. In other words, every time chrome is acting like I just installed it.

So, how can I make it open the chrome with cookies, etc. (I did not know how to explain that but hope you understand)?

Here is how I login:

```
global browser
browser = webdriver.Chrome()

def LogIn():
    
    browser.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")
    sleep(2)
    username = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='username']")
    password = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='password']")
    sleep(3)
    username.send_keys(kAdi)
    password.send_keys(sifre)
    loginButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type= 'submit']")
    loginButton.click()
    sleep(3)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Already requested here: [Saving chrome cookies Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39183753/saving-chrome-cookies-selenium)

To not open another window just execute JS window.open() function
And switch to the windows (or tabs) using SwitchTo() and windows.handler() Selenium methods.