# Powershell with Selenium 4.x: Chrome options

Tags: powershell, selenium

I am able to successfully execute a Powershell script with Selenium 4.x although i need to run chrome under a user profile (which will persist). The objective is to save the cookies. For that I believe I will need to add options as defined in [Saving chrome cookies Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39183753/saving-chrome-cookies-selenium). I do see something similar here although I need it for Powershell.

So how do I implement options that can be used by this command. (This command is primarily for selenium 4.x).

> $browser = Start-SeDriver -Browser Chrome

This is all I could get, but I am unsure how to add it all up:

> $ChromeOptions.addArguments("c:/users/PsUser");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With Module https://github.com/adamdriscoll/selenium-powershell v4:**

```
$browser = Start-SeDriver -Browser Chrome -Arguments "--user-data-dir=C:\Users\$($env:username)\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data"
```

**Without Module:**

When you instantiate the ChromeDriver object you can pass a ChromeOptions argument.
So basically:

```
# Your working directory
$workingPath = 'C:\selenium'

# Add the working directory to the environment path.
# This is required for the ChromeDriver to work.
if (($env:Path -split ';') -notcontains $workingPath) {
    $env:Path += ";$workingPath"
}

# OPTION 1: Import Selenium to PowerShell using the Add-Type cmdlet.
Add-Type -Path "$($workingPath)\WebDriver.dll"

# Create a new ChromeDriver Object instance.
$ChromeOptions = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions
$ChromeOptions.AddArgument("--user-data-dir=C:\Users\$($env:username)\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")

$ChromeDriver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver($ChromeOptions)

# Launch a browser and go to URL
$ChromeDriver.Navigate().GoToURL('https://google.com')

#  Cleanup
$ChromeDriver.Close()
$ChromeDriver.Quit()
```

Comment: The Start-SeChrome is with Selenium version 3.x. The version I am using is 4.x (https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Selenium/4.0.0-preview3) which uses Start-SeDriver . When I run with that I get "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ProfileDirectoryPath'." The command I run is   $browser = Start-SeDriver -Browser Chrome -ProfileDirectoryPath 'c:\temp\'

Comment: I misread this point. I've edited the answer :)