# Switching from headless browser to normal browser in python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

Is there any way to login into website using headless driver and show the resulted output page in a normal browser like Internet Explorer or Firefox.

I am currently using **python 2.7** and **selenium 2.47.3**

Comment: Do you mean a webdriver backed browser, or just any normal webbrowser started manually?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save and load cookies using python selenium webdriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058462/how-to-save-and-load-cookies-using-python-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: What would the purpose of this be? Why can't you login using a normal browser?

Comment: When login takes place I don't want to let the user close browser manually so I want the login process to be headless (i.e. the process should be hidden to user until desired page is loaded) but once desired page is loaded user should be able to see it in normal browser.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the best solution to this case is to use screeshoot to visualize the page. Try:

```
driver.get_screenshot_as_file('file.png')
```