# Getting cookies saved by firefox with python

Tags: javascript, python, firefox, cookies

Is there any way to get cookies saved by Firefox with python code? I think its possible to interact with Firefox javascript interpreter with python but i don't know how.

Actually i need firefox to browse a Web page, the Web page has some sort of authentications and finaly it makes a session key cookie, I want know cookie value and of course automatically with python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), fire up a browser, navigate to a page, make the desired actions on a page and then use [`get_cookies()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.get_cookies) to extract the cookies:

> Returns a set of dictionaries, corresponding to cookies visible in the current session.

```
from selenium import webdriver 

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")

# do something else if needed

print(driver.get_cookies())
```

You can even dump and load cookies if needed:

- [How to save and load cookies using python selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058462/how-to-save-and-load-cookies-using-python-selenium-webdriver)