# Selenium and Goodreads' pagination

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract information from Goodreads. The problem is if I go into a url like:

> https://www.goodreads.com/shelf/show/programming?page=2

with Selenium chrome webdriver or with BeautifulSoup, it still shows the first page, instead of the second one.
Example with the chrome webdriver:

[image: Example with the chrome webdriver]

While on a normal browser, it displays those books instead:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that happen because you're not logged-in  in your selenium session, you will have to login and save the cookies between restarts.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058462/how-to-save-and-load-cookies-using-python-selenium-webdriver) stackoverflow answers to understand how to extract cookies.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you!