# Setting options parameter for Selenium Firefox webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver

I'm using Selenium's webdriver and GeckoDriverManager to open a website and take a screenshot in Firefox. That part works fine. I wanted to specify where to save this screenshot using selenium.webdriver.set_preference() to specify the download path and saving this under an options variable. If I use firefox_driver=webdriver.Firefox(service=service, **options=options**) the website no longer launches. This is the code I used to set the option preferences: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69974916

Does anyone have an idea where the problem might be coming from?

```
def load_driver():
    service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install())

    options = Options()
    options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False)
    options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
    options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", "image/png")
    options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "image/png")
    options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 1)

    firefox_driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service) #stops working if I add options=options parameter here

def getscreenshot():
    driver = load_driver()
    driver.get(website)
    sleep(3)
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file("screenshot.png")
    driver.quit()
    print("end...")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the absolute or relative path to the file in driver.get_screenshot_as_file(). The code below will save the screenshot in <current_dir>/image/.

```
def getscreenshot():
    driver = load_driver()
    driver.get(website)
    sleep(3)
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file("./image/screenshot.png")
    driver.quit()
    print("end...")
```