# Download Planner From Microsoft Tasks Using Python

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, ms-office

I'm trying to export a planner as an excel from Microsoft's Tasks/Planner website using python, selenium, and chrome. Selenium opens a new browser which lacks cookies and thus always gets prompted for credentials and - for my company - two-factor authentication. Based on other stack exchange posts, I have saved and used a cookie which resolved this issue. Is there a different and ideally better way to approach this problem? I'd just like to know.

Here's my code in case it helps someone facing a similar task.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os, time, datetime

import json
def save_cookie(driver, path): #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45417335/python-use-cookie-to-login-with-selenium
    with open(path, 'w') as filehandler:
        json.dump(driver.get_cookies(), filehandler)

def load_cookie(driver, path):
    with open(path, 'r') as cookiesfile:
        cookies = json.load(cookiesfile)
    for cookie in cookies:
        cookie.pop("domain")
        driver.add_cookie(cookie)

url = "https://tasks.office.com/path/to/planner"
menu_selector = '//button[@title="More. Navigate to other pages related to this plan."]'
save_selector = "Export plan to Excel"

#r = requests.Session()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\chromedriver.exe")

#Go to domain cookies rely on
driver.get("https://tasks.office.com/")
#load cookies
load_cookie(driver, r"C:\Users\user\Downloads\cookies.json")
driver.get(url) #go to actual website

authenticated = 'definitive_text_segment_from_url' in driver.current_url

if not authenticated: #Login to refresh cookie if stale.
    username = input("Please provide a username")
    password = input("Please provide a password")

    driver.find_element_by_name("loginfmt").send_keys(username)
    driver.find_element_by_name("loginfmt").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    
    
    driver.find_element_by_name("pf.username").send_keys(username)
    driver.find_element_by_name("pf.pass").send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element_by_name("pf.pass").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    authentification_code = input("Please provide the authentification code.")
    
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(menu_selector)
elem.click() #clicks on three dots
elem = driver.find_element_by_name(save_selector)
elem.click() #clicks on export planner option and autosaves file

save_cookie(driver, r"C:\Users\user\Downloads\cookies.json")
```

Comment: Can't you use the [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/planner-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0)?

Comment: @RJAdriaansen Thanks for your response! Yeah, I didn't see an option to export as an excel when I looked at it and skipped to the easier option of selenium + cookies. But now that I've looked at it further it seems doable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Edge driver instead of Chrome? For me launching Edge through Microsoft's Edge driver bypasses a lot of Microsoft related log in steps.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31339632)