# How to save cookies for later test runs with Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

On a dev environment that I have to run test automation, there is google authentication every time I want to access the dev URL, but it triggers a captcha due to the number of attempts. Can I somehow save the cookies, so when I open a new instance I am already logged in with google and I do not have to login every single time.

I asked ChatGPT for solutions, it didn't work;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send cookies with selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340373/how-to-send-cookies-with-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

this cookie solution I found is helpful,  it can solved my problem, you should try.

It can save and load cookie
[Python: use cookie to login with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45417335/python-use-cookie-to-login-with-selenium)

Comment: This is with Python, I need solution with java, I do not understand python well so I will not be able to convert it