# Prevent Selenium Version 4 from Creating Temprary Firefox Profiles?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, webdriver

I've been using Selenium v3 (Geckodriver) and I noticed some exciting new features in [Selenium v4](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2021/selenium-4-beta-1/) (which I believe is still in beta). I want to migrate my entire code base to v4. However, my current test suite relies on using existing FF Profiles to launch Selenium.

I want to prevent Selenium v4 from copying the permanent FF Profile to a temporary directory. Is this possible?

P.S

I found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67561490/how-to-prevent-selenium-3-0-geckodriver-from-creating-temporary-firefox-profil) in relation to Selenium v3. However, I am specifically asking how to achieve this in Selenium v4 *which uses an entirely different approach to accessing existing profiles*.

Comment: What have you tried and how did it fail?