# Force WebDriver to use an Exisitng Firefox Profile in Geckdriver 0.30.0 without Creating Temporary Copy?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, rust, geckodriver

By default, **Geckodriver 0.30.0** copies existing FF profile to temporary files directory before launching a new instance of `WebDriver`.

The code responsible for this is written in `Rust` and is present in `src/browser.rs` of [geckodriver source](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.30.0), in line 60 - 70 [as discussed in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70500365/8814573):

```
 let mut profile = match options.profile {
     Some(x) => x,
     None => Profile::new()?,
  };
```

I’m able to permanently force `Geckodriver 0.30.0` to use a specific FF Profile directly (w/o first making a copy of it) by modifying the above code to:

```
let path = std::path::Path::new("path-to-profile");
let mut profile = Profile::new_from_path(path)?;
```

However, this would only allow me to use a single profile in the entire application as the `path_to_profile` is hard coded into above file.

I need to be able to launch **hundreds of FF profiles** throughout the lifecycle of my application and thus need to choose any existing profile at runtime using the following code structure:

```
File firefoxProfileFile= new File(path_to_profile_file);
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile(firefoxProfileFile);
FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
firefoxOptions.setProfile(firefoxProfile);
```

Using the code above it would be possible to dynamically select any existing FF profile at runtime, without first copying profile to temporary folder - but only if I can somehow pass the path to profile as an argument to above code.

How can this be done?

Comment: Just create a contructor with `path_to_profile_file` as arg. `WebDriver startGeckoDriver(String path_to_profile_file) {WebDriver driver = ...;   return driver;   }` and call `WebDriver driver1 = startGeckoDriver(path1);   WebDriver driver2 = startGeckoDriver(path2);`

Comment: @pburgr This won't create a temp folder first? I think it does..