# How to save the session of Whatsapp web with Selenium Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My expectation was something would get added to the cookeies array automatically after validation but that isn't the case.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
whatsapp_url = "https://web.whatsapp.com"
driver.get(whatsapp_url)
print(driver.get_cookies())
time.sleep(30) # We are doing the manual QR code verification here
print(driver.get_cookies())
```

`driver.get_cookies()` is empty before and after as well

Comment: you can use pickle

Comment: I am aware of that( https://stackoverflow.com/a/15058521/865220) just for QR code none of my experimentations are working. Can you give the full working code for saving QR code of whatsapp.

Comment: you can save whole session with chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=" + 
os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

Comment: full working code in answer please, very difficult to understand from 1-2 lines in comment.

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions();
options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=./User_Data')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
```

You need to login first time.
It'll work always when you have to store your session. No need to import/export cookies.

Comment: I tried this method. However, it doesn't work. QR code is still needed to login

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't comment Abhi Bhalgami answer but I need to made some changes based on another post:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chromepath = r'E:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromepath, chrome_options=options)
```

[extract and save whatsapp session from chrome browser local storage and then use it on another device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58928861/extract-and-save-whatsapp-session-from-chrome-browser-local-storage-and-then-use)

Answer (score 2):

*https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/241604/salva-o-estado-ou-os-cookies-do-navegador-utilizando-o-selenium*

This worked fine for me! I

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver

dir_path = os.getcwd()
profile = os.path.join(dir_path, "profile", "wpp")
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(
    r"user-data-dir={}".format(profile))

browser = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)

browser.get("https://web.whatsapp.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

am not sure but You can save your current cookies using pickle, For example:

```
import pickle
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
pickle.dump( driver.get_cookies() , open("cookies.pkl","wb"))
```

after that add them back using this code:

```
import pickle
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

Answer (score 0):

Web Whatsapp stores sessions in IndexedDB and sync those values to local storage.

Here is the working code you can try: [tithiwa/session.py](https://github.com/Tithibots/tithiwa/blob/main/tithiwa/session.py) by using this [javascript code](https://github.com/Tithibots/tithiwa/blob/main/tithiwa/constants.py#L113)

Comment: is this still working Sir? i've tried several times but with no luck.. could you please show the correct way?