# Can't get cookies with selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, cookies

Hi guys i was trying to get cookies in selenium . I used

```html
driver.get_cookies()
cookies_list = driver.get_cookies()
cookies_dict = {} # create dictionary
for cookie in cookies_list:
    cookies_dict[cookie['name']] = cookie['value'] # populate it

print(cookies_dict)
```

but the only result i get is {} , how i can manage to do that ?

Comment: i'm running chrome webdriver

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058462/how-to-save-and-load-cookies-using-python-selenium-webdriver

Comment: @thebadguy  'driver.get("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo")

pickle.dump( driver.get_cookies() , open("cookies.pkl","wb"))
time.sleep(60)
cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)


driver.get("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo")' i have tried to do that to save captcha coockies but seems not to work , why if i reload the page i have to redo the captcha ?