# How to set cookies on Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

How to set cookies on Selenium in Python?

```
session = request.Session()
auth = session.get(url + 'consulta/insumo/initFilter.action')

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.add_cookie(json.loads(json.dumps(dict(session.cookies))))
driver.get(url + 'consulta/insumo/update.action')
```

An error is returned while executing this:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: missing field `name` at line 1 column 28
```

Firefox is down.

Comment: It's a little bit different. I want to add Cookie from a previous request return.

Comment: @marcelo.delta see the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15058521/8179099 you can use `pickle.load`