# Does the chromedriver used with Python Selenium store cookies

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cookies, selenium-chromedriver

So my question is very simple. I would like know each time I run a selenium application using chromedriver, does it start with a blank slate? Or does it store cookies from last the last applicaion?

Comment: Why not try it yourself?  Seems straightforward...

Comment: There's the same question here: [How to save and load cookies using Python + Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058462/how-to-save-and-load-cookies-using-python-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: @Kafels does that mean that by default, cookies are not stored, and each new application gets a clean slate?

Answer (score 1):

Selenium creates a temporary profile for each session, since profiles hold all the cookies, history, cache and settings for the browser the answer is no, it doesnt store cookies or any information from previous sessions.

That is if you don't explicitly override it with a custom profile dir when instantiating your driver

Comment: This is somewhat misleading. The answer is: **yes** it does store cookies. However, when you dismiss the browser the profile is deleted. When you relaunch the browser, a new (empty) profile is created.