# How to save and load cookies using Ruby + Selenium WebDriver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium-webdriver

How can I save all cookies in Ruby's Selenium WebDriver to a txt-file, then load them later? I don't find any answer which does export and import at the same time

In python looks like a very easy way to do that, how to do it in RUBY?

[How to save and load cookies using Python + Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058462/how-to-save-and-load-cookies-using-python-selenium-webdriver):

```py
import pickle
import selenium.webdriver 

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
pickle.dump( driver.get_cookies() , open("cookies.pkl","wb"))
```

Edits:
I am only using Selenium WebDriver (no capybara etc)

Answer (score 2):

In tests you can use gem [show_me_the_cookies](https://github.com/nruth/show_me_the_cookies) (a wrapper/adapter)

```rb
cookies = show_me_the_cookies # => [{:name, :domain, :value, :expires, :path, :secure}]
# here you can write them as you like
# and then load and
cookies.each{|c|
  create_cookie(c[:name], c[:value], path: c[:path], domain: c[:domain]) # etc.
}
```

Without gems you can call directly to selenium driver:

```rb
driver = Capybara.current_session.driver # or get your selenium driver other way if not using capybara
cookies = driver.browser.manage.all_cookies
# be sure that you've visited a page in your app, selenium cannot create cookies at `about:blank`
driver.browser.manage.add_cookie(name: ..., value:...)
```

Comment: I am using only selenium webdriver