# How to save and load all cookies using Java + Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cookies, webdriver

How can I save all cookies (from all domains, not just the current domain) in Java's Selenium WebDriver to a .txt file, and then load all of them when I restore Selenium session?

`driver.manage().getCookies()` only returns cookies from the current domain and `addCookie()` only adds one cookie at a time.

[This question addresses Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058462/how-to-save-and-load-cookies-using-python-selenium-webdriver) while [this question only addresses Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56338704/how-to-save-and-load-cookies-using-ruby-selenium-webdriver).

How can I achieve this in Java?

Thanks!