# How to fix "invalid argument: invalid 'expiry'" in Selenium when adding cookies to a chromedriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to add cookies to a browser, but getting the following error:

Message: invalid argument: invalid 'expiry'
(Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.90)

This code shows how I load and add cookies.

```
for cookie in pickle.load(open(r'{0}\{1}_cookie.pkl'.format(settings.COOKIES_PATH, self.tv_username), 'rb')):
    self.browser.add_cookie(cookie)
```

Values of the cookies:

```
{'__utmc': '226258911', '_sp_id.cf1a': '0b243b32-8dee-46d9-a243-bb4d2bfcb805.1560942815.1.1560942821.1560942815.5941cbc0-0500-4a17-8f6c-4ee3f133f67c', 'km_vs': '1', '__utmt': '1', '__utma': '226258911.510671571.1560942814.1560942814.1560942814.1', 'km_ai': 'm6caeIAUtEqx%2BIWda%2F7klZER%2F1Y%3D', 'kvcd': '1560942821112', '__utmb': '226258911.2.10.1560942814', 'km_lv': '1560942821', '__utmz': '226258911.1560942814.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)', 'etg': 'undefined', '_sp_ses.cf1a':'*'}
```

It worked fine with previous version of chrome. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you try the latest version of `chromedriver`?

Comment: I tried and got: "Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 76".

Comment: Can you show us the value of the cookies??

Comment: @JoseMartínezPoquet I added values in question description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to add the cookies with a different format than the selenium expects.

The [python selenium api reference](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.add_cookie) says that you have to insert the cookies with a dict like that

```
driver.add_cookie({'name' : 'foo', 'value' : 'bar'})
```

So you have to adapt your loop to use a key,value format

```
for key, value in pickle.load(open(r'{0}\{1}_cookie.pkl'.format(settings.COOKIES_PATH, self.tv_username), 'rb')):
    self.browser.add_cookie({'name' : key, 'value' : value})
```

Answer (score 27):

In my case, the previous answer did not work. I had to remove the expire key from the object.

```
 for cookie in pickle.load(open(PATH, "rb")):
     if 'expiry' in cookie:
         del cookie['expiry']

     self.driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

This happens if you previously pickled the cookies directly as they're returned from the driver, like so:

```
pickle.dump(browser.get_cookies(), open(PATH, "wb"))
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this. Nothing else I tried worked. Strange how this happens only on certain configurations. I could not isolate to exact version of pickle or exact config.

Comment: The reason the 'expiry' values are being rejected by newer versions of chromedriver is because of this change: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/c83119b466cfd63fd1eb616ee86b22ede5db3c4e%5E%21/#F4

Comment: When your chromedriver is in w3c compliant mode, it now requires that 'expiry' be an int64, whereas in legacy mode it will accept doubles. So you can either convert your expiry keys to integer (multiply them by 1000 to get ms), or you can disable w3c compliance via the ChromeOptions when initializing your session: ```chrome_options.add_experimental_option("w3c", False)```

Comment: This has been confirmed as a bug in chromedriver and will be fixed in a future release: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3331

Comment: This works if you don't care about `expiry`, but it is technically modifying the original cookies. To preserve the original cookies, see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61845727/3862439

Answer (score 13):

In my version of python and selenium, I have found that on there is a difference between how Selenium outputs cookie expiry values and how it imports them. When you use

```
driver.get_cookies()
```

the driver can output expiry values that are floats rather than integers. These floats seem to be epoch time units (number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970). If you try to add these exact cookies back into driver, they will fail because the driver only accepts cookies with integer expiry values. In this line:

```
driver.add_cookie({'name': name, 'value': value, 'expiry': expiry})
```

the value of expiry MUST be an integer. Otherwise, you will get the value error. I fixed this using the following code.

```
# Saving current cookies and reformatting them
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
for cookie in cookies:
    if 'expiry' in cookie:
        cookie['expiry'] = int(cookie['expiry'])
    # Adding cookies back into the driver
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

This worked for me, and I no longer get an error.

Comment: This is also wrong (it modifies the cookie) (you need to multiply by 1000, see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56663666/how-to-fix-invalid-argument-invalid-expiry-in-selenium-when-adding-cookies/61845727#comment106164695_57122470) or [the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61845727/5267751))

Comment: For my version, this is correct. Multiplying expiry by 1000 gives ms. When you add them back, the driver is expecting 'expiry' to be in seconds, not ms.

Comment: Perhaps you should mention your chrome&chromedriver&selenium version in the post. // also because the bug is fixed, in newer versions the cookies might be *stored* as int64 too.

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by an active bug in chromedriver: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3331

The bug is that chromedriver returns `expiry` cookies with `get_cookies` as a double, but does not accept a double for it with `add_cookie`. Here's the fix:

```
for cookie in pickle.load(open('cookies.pkl', 'rb')):
    expiry = cookie.get('expiry', None)

    if expiry:
      cookie['expiry'] = int(expiry * 1000)
    browser.add_cookie(cookie)
```

Comment: Why the multiplication by 1000?

Comment: @ScottDriggers "to get ms" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56663666/how-to-fix-invalid-argument-invalid-expiry-in-selenium-when-adding-cookies/61845727#comment106164695_57122470