# How can i fix “invalid argument: invalid 'expiry'” in Selenium when adding cookies to a chromedriver?

Tags: selenium, cookies, pickle

“invalid argument: invalid 'expiry'”

I'm trying to add cookies to a browser, but getting the following error:
How to fix “invalid argument: invalid 'expiry'” in Selenium when adding cookies to a chromedriver?

```
pickle.dump( driver.get_cookies() , open("cookies.pkl","wb"))

driver.get ( URL )
sleep ( 2 )

cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb")) 
for cookie in cookies: 
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
    sleep(2)

driver.get ( URL )

print(driver.get_cookies())
pickle.dump( driver.get_cookies() , open("cookies.pkl","wb"))
```

Error msg

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: invalid 'expiry'
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)
```

Comment: I think answer is here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56663666/how-to-fix-invalid-argument-invalid-expiry-in-selenium-when-adding-cookies

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "invalid argument: invalid 'expiry'" in Selenium when adding cookies to a chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56663666/how-to-fix-invalid-argument-invalid-expiry-in-selenium-when-adding-cookies)

Answer (score 3):

first of all follow link from comment to change pickle to dict 
see also this 
https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#add-cookie point 6
expiry should be now `int` not `float`.

```
for cookie in cookies:
    if isinstance(cookie.get('expiry'), float):
        cookie['expiry'] = int(cookie['expiry'])
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason the 'expiry' values are being rejected by newer versions of chromedriver is because of this change: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/c83119b466cfd63fd1eb616ee86b22ede5db3c4e%5E%21/#F4

When your chromedriver is in w3c compliant mode, it now requires that 'expiry' be an int64, whereas in legacy mode it will continue to accept the old float values.

The problem (and it may be a bug in chromedriver), is that `driver.get_cookies()` continues to return 'expiry' values as floats, while `driver.add_cookie(...)` does not accept these cookies back.

So to get around this for now, you have two options:

1. Convert your expiry keys to an integer (multiply them by 1000 to get milliseconds): `cookie["expiry"] = int(cookie["expiry"]*1000)` before passing them to `driver.add_cookie(...)`

OR

2. Disable w3c compliance on your chromedriver session, by adding an experimental flag to ChromeOptions:

```
from selenium import webdriver

opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opt.add_experimental_option('w3c', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opt)
```

Comment: This has been confirmed as a bug in chromedriver and will be fixed in a future release: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3331

Answer (score 0):

this issue has been fixed in ChromeDriver-83
and the version is released:

> ```
> Resolved issue 3331: The get_cookies() method is returning 'expiry' keys of type double, but should be int64 in w3c mode
> ```