# Importing cookies to Selenium doesn't work

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cookies, selenium-chromedriver

After logging on Facebook, I received cookies using the method `driver.get_cookies()`

Output:

```
[{'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1609944355, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'fr', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': '19KsJJcu9iZcNDw80.AWUnObiYyWlbmsSbMaAoTBQ3Qkg.BffyYn.EY.AAA.0.0.BffyYq.AWWxZSl5V8s'}, {'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1633704358, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'xs', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': '4%3A8K8IO-G4AqVxpw%3A2%3A1602168362%3A-1%3A-1'}, {'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1633704358, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'c_user', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': '100055628751137'}, {'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1665240357, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'datr', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': 'JyZ_X5OBe55yRMjKU-d8nSYQ'}, {'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1602773165, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'dpr', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': '1.25'}, {'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1602258362, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'spin', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': 'r.1002790228_b.trunk_t.1602168365_s.1_v.2_'}, {'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1602773164, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'wd', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'Lax', 'secure': True, 'value': '1036x684'}, {'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1665240361, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'sb', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': 'JyZ_XwAJTQy5L-W6Ivkp2MBC'}]
```

Then I saved them in the variable `cookies` and when I tried to import cookies through the `driver.add_cookie()` method, I get an exception:

```
InvalidArgumentException
Message: invalid argument: missing 'cookie'
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.121)
```

The code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://facebook.com')

cookies = "[{'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1609944355, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'fr', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': '19KsJJcu9iZcNDw80.AWUnObiYyWlbmsSbMaAoTBQ3Qkg.BffyYn.EY.AAA.0.0.BffyYq.AWWxZSl5V8s'}, {'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1633704358, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'xs', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': '4%3A8K8IO-G4AqVxpw%3A2%3A1602168362%3A-1%3A-1'}, {'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1633704358, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'c_user', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': '100055628751137'}, {'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1665240357, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'datr', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': 'JyZ_X5OBe55yRMjKU-d8nSYQ'}, {'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1602773165, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'dpr', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': '1.25'}, {'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1602258362, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'spin', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': 'r.1002790228_b.trunk_t.1602168365_s.1_v.2_'}, {'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1602773164, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'wd', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'Lax', 'secure': True, 'value': '1036x684'}, {'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1665240361, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'sb', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': 'JyZ_XwAJTQy5L-W6Ivkp2MBC'}]"

driver.add_cookie(cookies)
driver.get('https://facebook.com')
```

Tried adding in a cycle:

```
for cookie in cookies:
  driver.add_cookie({'cookie' : cookie})
```

Nothing helps... What am I doing wrong?

PS: I've already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56663666/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you are almost there.

The argument of this function `add_cookie(cookie_dict)` is in **dictionary** form, so parse the cookies you got into dictionary before using them.

Try this code:

```py
cookies = [{'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1609944355, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'fr', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': '19KsJJcu9iZcNDw80.AWUnObiYyWlbmsSbMaAoTBQ3Qkg.BffyYn.EY.AAA.0.0.BffyYq.AWWxZSl5V8s'}, {'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1633704358, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'xs', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': '4%3A8K8IO-G4AqVxpw%3A2%3A1602168362%3A-1%3A-1'}, {'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1633704358, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'c_user', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': '100055628751137'}, {'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1665240357, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'datr', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': 'JyZ_X5OBe55yRMjKU-d8nSYQ'}, {'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1602773165, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'dpr', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': '1.25'}, {'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1602258362, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'spin', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': 'r.1002790228_b.trunk_t.1602168365_s.1_v.2_'}, {'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1602773164, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'wd', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'Lax', 'secure': True, 'value': '1036x684'}, {'domain': '.facebook.com', 'expiry': 1665240361, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'sb', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'None', 'secure': True, 'value': 'JyZ_XwAJTQy5L-W6Ivkp2MBC'}]

for cookie in cookies:
  driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

Comment: Yes, it works. But if I get cookies to a string, then how do I convert that string to a list?

Comment: For example, if I take cookies from a file

Comment: The method driver.get_cookies() needs an argument in dictionary form. The method does not care how or where you get the dictionary, so no matter taking cookies from a file or String or list, just remember to change it to a dictionary. It depends on the specific scenario, and I cannot give more details.