# selenium - how to store machine token and reuse it?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate some processes on an OTP authenticated account and using `selenium-webdriver` `firefox`. The system asks me for an OTP after login with the option to paraphrase don't ask for otp on this system.

The problem is when I launch the program again, after login it asks for OTP again. Which doesn't happen if I launch a normal instance of `Firefox`.

Is there a way to store/use the machine token over again using selenium firefox?

Thanks

Comment: If the OTP is stored in a cookie, the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058462/how-to-save-and-load-cookies-using-python-selenium-webdriver

Comment: Keep in mind that you can add the cookie, only after you open the page with the related domain.

Comment: @Jonah yes I made that mistake after Tom's answer and then fixed it. :)