# Authentication cookies not reusable with selenium chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium 3.141.0 with chromedriver 86.0.4240.22 to log into a website, store the cookies. During the next session I wish to use the existing cookies to prevent doing the log in again. However, it does not work. Everything seems to run fine, but the site https://primexbt.com does not ack the existing cookies. What can I do?

```
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--dns-prefetch-disable')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--lang=en-US')
    options.add_argument('--disable-setuid-sandbox')
    chrome_prefs = {
        'intl.accept_languages': 'en-US',
    }
    options.add_experimental_option('prefs', chrome_prefs)
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

    # load cookies
    cookies = get_cookies()
    if cookies:
        self.driver.get(self.URL_PRIMEXBT)
        for cookie in cookies:


            self.driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default - a new ChromeDriver session creates a new profile data dir - so you don't have cookies from your previous session. I would suggest to either:

1. Start WebDriver with a profile data that contains your authorization cookie

```
options.add_argument('user-data-dir')
```

2. Do the authorization by direct http call/API call, bypassing WebDriver (to speed up the test) - and pass the response cookies to WebDriver
3. Or store authorization cookies and load them - e.g. using this solution:
   [How to save and load cookies using Python + Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058462/how-to-save-and-load-cookies-using-python-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: As I've stated I am saving and loading the cookies correctly, I can see that during debugging.

Comment: Could you share get_cookies implementation?

Comment: And could you check if cookie properties of properly set cookie are the same that properties of cookie added by add_cookie selenium method (especially - Domain)?

Comment: hi, it works if I use `options.add_argument('user-data-dir`. If you can replace the bullets with that then I'll accept. Using profile I don't even need to re-add the cookies as it is included. Got the idea from your 1st sentence, thanks :)

Comment: hi - I've added this solution with starting WebDriver with a profile data