# Fun Captcha Arkose Labs

Tags: python, selenium, captcha

I am taking my first steps in writing tests in Python Selenium.
I wrote a test that fills in the login fields on a certain page.
Unfortunately, funCaptcha from Arkose Labs "killed me."
Is there any fairly simple solution to overcome this problem?

I tried to simulate the user's behavior as much as possible.
I typed characters in the fields with second intervals.
I paused the script for 1/2 second simulating a man wondering what he was doing - at different points in the program, etc.

All instructions from Api Key are black magic to me so far :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUuE6.png)

Answer (score 0):

You may get the cookies from the site once and upload it into the same website (different page with no captcha) ***every time*** before you try to get to the page with the captcha this will bypass any login forms.

Check this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15058521/15106950

Wish you Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I'm afraid the amount of code in this link has overwhelmed me :).

But to simplify if I understand correctly:

1.I should manually go through this captcha.
2. Download selenium cookies with defeated captcha
3.And when writing the test, before I go to the login page, tell selenium to load it?

Comment: Perfect ! You got it