# Save/Load Cookies with Python Selenium + Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, cookies, webdriver

I'd like to ask for a 2021 code revision of this old question: [How to save and load cookies using Python + Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058462/how-to-save-and-load-cookies-using-python-selenium-webdriver)

I'm specifically interested in the solution using Chrome to automatically manage your cookies in separate profile folders.

My objective is to have a folder on desktop as a standalone virtual environment, so all cookies will be saved in that folder and loaded from that same folder the next time you launch a Selenium instance.

In an effort to find the cleanest solution, I stumbled upon these code snippets:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=selenium") 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("www.google.com")
```

This first solution doesn't work for me. I was given a deprecation warning for "chrome_options", so changed that to just "options", but the code still doesn't work throwing some errors.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
```

What I can't understand here is the difference between using "ChromeOptions()" rather than "Options()". I also don't get why the path is passed directly as an argument instead of using "options.add_argument".

As I said at the beginning, I'm striving to find the cleanest solution for storing/loading cookies in a separate folder environment using Python Selenium + Chrome. This of course implies using the latest syntax updated to 2021.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=selenium") 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

You'd have to use options like so otherwise you'd get a depreciation warning from chrome options.

Comment: What's the difference between "Options()" and "ChromeOptions()"?

Comment: It's just one's an older version so it's depreciated as in it's not up to date.

Comment: I get an error at line `driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)`

Comment: Did you change user data dir to your path.

Comment: --user-data-dir=C:\Users\ \AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data something like this.

Comment: executable_path=r'C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe also you can remove this if it's environment variables PATH otherwise not.

Comment: Now I get error at `driver.get("www.google.com")`: https://pastebin.com/gDJLyFcb

Comment: Oh right, I was troubleshooting and forgot to change that back. Now I'm getting the original error I mentioned before: https://pastebin.com/mYvb7L5z

Comment: Apprently it was a bug caused by leftover processes running in the background.