# Can you not get detected as a robot when using selenium in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've been trying to scrape this website for 2 days now. I'm completely stuck. The problem is that it detects me as a bot.

I have a list of urls that I need to crawl. and in the results folder, every file says that `Access to this page has been denied... To continue, please prove you are not a robot... etc.`

Below is my current code

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = './chromedriver'

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
ua = UserAgent()
userAgent = ua.random
chrome_options.add_argument('user-agent={userAgent}')

LOGIN_PAGE = "https://www.seekingalpha.com/login"
ACCOUNT = "Account"
PASSWORD = "Password"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36'})
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://www.seekingalpha.com/login")
time.sleep(1)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "email"))).send_keys(ACCOUNT)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "signInPasswordField"))).send_keys(PASSWORD)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Sign in']"))).click()

time.sleep(1)

with open("links.txt", "r") as inArticle:
    articles = inArticle.read().splitlines()

for article in articles:
    outName = article.split("/")[-1]
    outName = outName.split("-")[0]

    driver.get(article)
    time.sleep(1)
    html_source = driver.page_source

    out_text = str(html_source).encode("utf8")

    with open("./results/"+outName, "w") as outFile:
        outFile.write(out_text)

driver.quit()
```

Is there a better way to do this? and is there a way to pass this bot check?

Comment: It's strange indeed. Maybe your IP address got blacklisted? I think your code should work in theory?

Comment: It only asks to verify that you are not a robot, this is something you can also get as a human, when you are using VPN for example. Now a possible way to handle these is by providing cookies, such that the site knows that you have already been there before. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058462/how-to-save-and-load-cookies-using-python-selenium-webdriver) can help you, by first manually logging in using selenium and storing all the cookie data.

Comment: This is perimiterx I believe. Yes they can detect that you are a bot.

Comment: Did you try using undetected-chromedriver or [Selenium-Profiles](https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Profiles) ?