# How do I import cookies from any browser (preferably IE) to selenium Chrome driver?

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, selenium-chromedriver

I want to add my cookies from IE from a particular website to selenium browser by way of import.

Imports I currently have if they are any help to you.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can save the current cookies as a Python object using pickle. For example:

```
import pickle
import selenium.webdriver

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
pickle.dump( driver.get_cookies() , open("cookies.pkl","wb"))
```

And later to add them back:

```
import pickle
import selenium.webdriver

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058462/how-to-save-and-load-cookies-using-python-selenium-webdriver)

Edit: [Be careful when you pickle things. This is a great way to have a deserialization vulnerability introduced into your application.](https://zetcode.com/python/pickle/)

Comment: Websites have too many cookies. Its almost impossible to add cookies manually to driver object via json data. This method is very awesome and pratic. I log in manually at once and save cookies for future uses.