# Save Selenium logged in state

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

There is a site i am trying to accesss programatically. This site has 2fa. It texts me the code. I log in (all above board - just trying to automate my own account).

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    def loadpage():
        driver.get("link")
        time.sleep(2)
        userbox = driver.find_element("id", "signInName")
        userbox.send_keys(username)
        pwbox = driver.find_element("id", "password")
        pwbox.send_keys(password)
        #wait until i have completed 2fa and continue
```

I can log in. And then in subsequent calls to selenium driver the page does not askf for 2fa. At least for a while. It does after some time or some amount of log ins (it does not seem to ask for 2fa at all after the initial when i am not using selenium). is there a way to either A) transport my logged in state from another browser session or B) grab the cookies when I am logged in and inject them into the next session ? or am i screwed ?

i tried this [stack overflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058462/how-to-save-and-load-cookies-using-python-selenium-webdriver) but got an error about cookie domain mismatch.

any help or insight appreciated.

Comment: easiest way would be to add an account/profile to Chrome.  Log that profile in manually.  Close the browser.  Then launch Selenium/Chrome setting ChromeOptions to use that profile.  That would retain any "remember me" type info.  (it may or may not help you in this case since session info will not be retained)