# G2G selenium sessions

Tags: python, json, selenium-webdriver, web

I used code from [How to save and load cookies using Python + Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058462/how-to-save-and-load-cookies-using-python-selenium-webdriver) but it doesn't work for https://www.g2g.com/. Another example

```
import pickle
from selenium import webdriver
import time

#load cookie function
def seleniumLoadCookie():
    #creating a webdriver object
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    try:
        cookies = pickle.load(open("cookie.pkl", "rb")) #loading from pickle file
        for cookie in cookies:
            driver.add_cookie()
        print('Cookies added.')

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    
    driver.get("https://www.g2g.com")  #opening the url
    time.sleep(30)

    pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open("cookie.pkl", "wb")) #writing in pickle file


#driver
if __name__ == "__main__":
    seleniumLoadCookie()  #call the function
```

I want to save sessions and reuse them later.

Comment: Maybe try using [playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro)? It is a much newer python library, works without a webdriver, and can definitely save cookies.